# Page refreshes even after e.preventDefault() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#btn-add-skills').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // function call goes here
    });
```

Even after calling `e.preventDefault()`the page still gets refreshed on clicking the button.
Any suggestion what I might have missed?

Below is the JADE code for above on click function.

```
.modal-add-skills.modal.fade
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        h4(style='color: black !important;')
      .modal-body
        form#addSkills
          .form-group
            label.col-form-label(for='Skill') Skill
            input#skill_input.form-control.required(type='text', name='Skill', placeholder='Start typing to select skill', style="width: 300px;")
          .modal-footer
            button#add-skill-data.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Add
```

Comment: Can you post the html element which is having `btn-add-skills`?

Comment: can you show the HTML markup of `id="btn-add-skills"` ?

Comment: Is `btn-add-skills` within a parent `form` and of `type="submit"`?

Answer (score 6):

You may need to also add [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-add-skills').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        alert("Stopped Redirecting");

        // function call goes here

        return false;
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dw24yksw/)